# Can't unlock the full Bend will shout

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I'm on the [**At the Summit of Apocrypha**](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:At_the_Summit_of_Apocrypha) quest line where I have to unlock the [**bend will**](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Bend_Will) shout.. I have already learned the *Earth* but of the shout but I can't learn *Mind* and *Dragon* because I don't have any dragon souls saved up, And I can't absorb any more souls thanks to [**Miraak**](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Miraak_%28NPC%29) stealing them all from me.

Anyone know what I can do or is it game-over for me?

Comment: He doesn't always show up and steal your dragon souls.

Comment: Try absorbing a dragon soul outside of the Solstheim region. I've noticed Miraak will typically absorb the souls of the more powerful dragons such as the Serpentine Dragon and/or the Elder Dragons. You shouldn't need to restart your entire campaign to resolve this.

Comment: I've been having this issue. Even in Skyrim mainland he comes and hassles me. Taken 4/4 of souls so far.

Answer (score 1):

Based off previous threads (mainly on neoseeker, I would suggest checking them out), Miraak becomes quite a hindrance /insert speculation because the developers assume players have completed the main quest line by this point and/or have dragon souls stockpiled up /end speculation.

some have posted their solution for avoiding their souls being stolen:
1) Save your game right when a dragon you're fighting reaches low health, and then kill it. Even in Skyrim Miraak wont always come and steal your soul, so if it does happen, simply reload and kill the dragon again until Miraak doesn't come and take it.
2) Killing a dragon on/over water will prevent Miraak from appearing.

Side note, once you unlock the second word of the shout, Miraak becomes less annoying.
Hope this helps!